# Bootstrap-3.1.0 bug in navbar from mobile devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my site looks like I've found bug in bootstrap navbar when I visit it from mobile device or zoom+ in chrome browser.
Here is screenshots:

100% - ok
[image]

zoom 150% - bug?
[image]

zoom 175% - ok again (same result had to be for 150% as well)
[image]

Is it bug? If so, how to fix it? I'm back-end developer, not front-end one, so I have some problems with it.
Here the link for the site if that can helps - [socratify.ru](http://socratify.ru)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can confirm that i have the same bug after upgrading to 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The default bootstrap css uses sensible media queries with breakpoints
at 768, 992 and 1200 px.  Mobile first, so the default behavior of the navbar menu is to hide it's button and show the nav items when the clients display is at least 768px (the 'small devices' breakpoint).  While these work in many situations, you can change them to work with your content.

You are currently using the default bootstrap css from the cdn which comes pre-baked with these breakpoints.  You can download the css and change the media queries yourself or...  Bootstrap has a tool to build a custom version at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. The 'Media queries breakpoints' section contains the associated less variables. You would want to mess with the 'small device' breakpoint to suit your needs.  Reference your custom css instead of the one from the cdn.  You can still serve up the javascript from their cdn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is a bug, your list items are just too wide, so it breaks. Try adding this css rule to override the navbar-nav margin at sizes above 768 (it worked in Chrome and FF):

```
@media (min-width:768px){
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: none is invalid property value for margin... (by chrome and firefox devepoment tools)

Comment: Good to know. How about this:    margin: 0 -5px 0 -5px;